# Matching partial objects to table data

Tags: karate

I'm currently evaluating Karate as a replacement for our own home-grown API tests. I have a service returning data like so:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "enabled": true,
      "foo": 1,
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

The properties in each item belongs do different features, and I would like to test them separately.

For example, to test for item enablement, I would like to check that the `enabled` property has the correct value for a given `id`.

I've tried setting it up like this;

```
Feature: Partial object matching
  Background:
    Given table items
    |id  |enabled|
    | '1'|true   |
    | '2'|true   |
    | '3'|false  |

  Scenario: match with all properties specified -- this passes
    * def response = { items: [ { id: '3', enabled: false }, { id: '1', enabled: true }, { id: '2', enabled: true } ] }
    * match $response.items contains only items


  Scenario: match with partial properties -- how can I make this pass (while also testing for something sensible)?
    * def response = { items: [ { id: '3', enabled: false, foo: 1 }, { id: '1', enabled: true, foo: 1 }, { id: '2', enabled: true, foo: 1 } ] }
    * match $response.items contains only items
```

The real `item` objects are fairly chunky, containing many more properties and nested objects, and I would rather not specify the full expected structure since they relate to many different features, and some properties are dynamic in nature.

Is there an elegant `match` to do this, or do i have to resort to scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the right thing;

```
Feature: Partial object matching
  Background:
    Given def filterTableKeys = read('filterTableKeys.js')
    Given table items
    |id  |enabled|
    | '1'|true   |
    | '2'|true   |
    | '3'|false  |

  Scenario: match with all attributes
    * def response = { items: [ { id: '3', enabled: false }, { id: '1', enabled: true }, { id: '2', enabled: true } ] }
    * match $response.items contains only items

  Scenario: match with partial attributes
    * def response = { items: [ { id: '3', enabled: false, foo: 1 }, { id: '1', enabled: true, foo: 1 }, { id: '2', enabled: true, foo: 1 } ] }
    * def responseItems = $response.items
    * def responseItems2 = filterTableKeys(responseItems, items)
    * match responseItems2 contains only items
```

where `filterTableKeys.js` is defined as

```
function fn(items, table) {
    var mapper = function(v) { return karate.filterKeys(v, table[0]) }
    return karate.map(items, mapper)
}
```

It doesn't feel very elegant though, so any hints on how it could be done more declarative/less imperative/"scripty" would be appreciated.

---

*Edit*

As [Babu Sekaran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929544/matching-partial-objects-to-table-data?noredirect=1#comment114800209_64932958) noted below, this seems to work nicely

```
  Scenario: match with partial attributes
    * def response = { items: [ { id: '3', enabled: false, foo: 1 }, { id: '1', enabled: true, foo: 1 }, { id: '2', enabled: true, foo: 1 } ] }
    * match $response.items contains deep items
```

Comment: you can try `* match $response.items contains deep items`

Comment: documentation for reference:- https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains-deep

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!